# command is not adding using yarg npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yargs

I am trying to add a command using yarg, but when I run my code my command is not added.

Here is what I am trying:

```
const yargs = require('yargs')

//create add command
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'to add note',
    handler: function() {
        console.log('note has been added')
    } 
})
```

run command:

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\node\notes-app> node app.js --help
Options:
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
```

No add command is added.

Also, when I try to run my code by giving add as an argument (i.e., node app.js add) nothing is shown.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'to add note',
    handler: function() {
        console.log('note has been added')
    } 
}).parse()
```

if u dont add parse(), yargs will not execute. if u have too many yargs commands type

```
yargs.parse()
```

or

```
console.log(yargs.argv)
```

down below.

Answer (score 0):

As per `yargs` docs, the method `command` takes 4 params and not an object;

`.command(cmd, desc, [builder], [handler])`

so your code should be something like (Notice, no more parentheses and object keys):

```
//create add command
yargs.command(
    'add',
    'to add note',
    function() {
        console.log('note has been added')
    } 
})
```

If you're not passing the optional `builder` param, should probably use named params, for the handler function (not sure how `yargs` have named the params, but i guess it's `handler`) like

```
   ...
   handler = function() {
        console.log('note has been added')
    }
```